# Finding controls/interface for addons

Tags: modeling, interface

After I enable an addon to add objects (for instance a gear from Extra Objects addon) the interface shows up in the toolbar menu. Is there any way to get the interface back after it has disappeared?

Edit: Thanks. That was not the answer I was looking for but I suppose that I will have to live with it.

Stephen

Comment: I'd say F6, but if it disapperas, that's also not possible any more - it doesn't disappear without a reason. > duplicate.

Comment: Did you make a new file? If you enabled the addon in one file and didn't save it in your user preferences, it won't appear in new files.